# "Voting" mechanism for XMPP protocol

Tags: xmpp, voting

I need to extend functionality of standard XMPP protocol, to be able perform voting sessions (in multi user chat). Please direct me - can I use some existing XEP(like Data Forms) or I need to implement some custom XEP ? 
Or better use some customized "message topic" labels, to treat some plain messages as special .

Will be grateful for any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

I believe a XEP-0004 data form, which you hand to a client could be a good building block for in-MUC voting. You still need to spec-up how the voting items are distributed and collected. A potential drawback if such a mechanism is purely data form based is that it would require client support. On the other hand, a pure text based voting system (e.g. voting bots) would allow every user to participate.

You could also use XEP-0050 "Ad-hoc commands", which is itself data form based and supported by some, if not the majority of, XMPP clients.

In summary it depends on your exact use case: for example if you have full control over the involved clients, and how much effort you want to put in it, and how the votes are exactly structured.

Is usually would prefer simple, but robust, text only solution, if there is nothing which speaks against it. But the XEP-0050 approach has also some appeal.